# How to use spacers in Qt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have a `QGroupBox` with assigned to it `QVBoxLayout`.

```
groupBox = QtGui.QGroupBox()
layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
groupBox.setLayout(layout )
```

Then there is a single `QLabel` assigned to the layout.

```
label = QtGui.QLabel()   
layout.addWidget(label)
```

The problem is that QLabel is positioned at the middle of the GroupBox. While I want it to be aligned with the top edge of the GroupBox. I probably need to add some sort of spacer. So the spacer would dynamically resize  itself to fill the GroupBox's empty area pushing QLabel upward.

What widget and what size policy should be used as a spacer?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
label = QtGui.QLabel()   
layout.addWidget(label)
verticalSpacer = QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
layout.addItem(verticalSpacer)
```

This should work

Comment: `layout.addStretch()`.

Answer (score 19):

In pyQt5 , the [QSpacerItem](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/api/qspaceritem.html) and [QSizePolicy](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/api/qsizepolicy.html) classes are now a part of QtWidgets so you'd want to create a vertical spacer in this manner...

```
verticalSpacer = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `pyqt==6.4.2` and  the structure changed a little bit. now you have to use `QSizePolicy.Policy` to access the `Minimum` and `Expanding` attributes.

```py
verticalSpacer = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding)
```